# TransactionManagementError in test of django model

Tags: django-models, django-testing, django-1.6

In django 1.6, I try test a unique field.

```
# model tag
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


# test unique of name field
class TagTest(TestCase):

    def test_tag_unique(self):
        t1 = Tag(name='music')
        t1.save()

        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):                                                                                                                    
          t2 = Tag(name='music')
          t2.save()

        self.assertEqual(['music'], [ t.name for t in Tag.objects.all() ])
```

with the last line I get this message

```
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

why ?

#### EDIT

I get this with sqlite as DB (Development Environment).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL then [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#handling-exceptions-within-postgresql-transactions) is why.

**Edit:**

See [this](https://github.com/django/django/commit/0d74bdaf0c39feb8ec303dbbdbcadba70e46eecb#diff-f8a587a973ef4c3a94d7550a5b85342cR362) commit. Since it's in base backend it seems like all backends now share common behavior. Despite the backend used, if the transaction needs rollback an error is raised.

*Tip:*

Use `Model.objects.create(attr="value")` instead of create and `.save()`.

Comment: I get this when I try the test with sqlite.